# Парсинг 2gis через request bs4 python

Tags: python, selenium, request, bs4

Коллеги, подскажите, есть ли у кого наработки по парсингу сайта 2гис через request и bs4?
Через selenium можно, но медленно и более нагруженный процесc.

Я знаю, что с requst парсят, но там заморочка с csrf токенами, но не могу найти более менее внятную инфу в инете.

Comment: уточните адрес сайта и какие данные парсите?

Comment: https://2gis.ru

Comment: и что оттуда нужно спарсить?

Comment: Не так важна информация, которую нужно парсить, предположим, каталог строительных компаний в Москве, меня интересует опыт других пользователей портала, как они проходят систему защиты от парсинга на портале 2gis.ru,
используя при парсинге request и bs4.

Comment: Есть вариант с реквестом но проблема в том что там при парсинге нужно бесконечно скролить чтобы получить всю инфу с сайта а с этой проблемой реквест не справится к сожалению
(
requests в headers добавь из DEv tools са данные заголовки потом уже получиться